# Group dataset based on a rule?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the folowing data set:

```
Zone    Car      FiscalYear Rating  FinalRating     Year   Bool
----------------------------------------------------------------
Zone1   Mercedes    2020    green     green          2020   1
Zone1   Mercedes    2020    green     green          2021   0
Zone1   Mercedes    2021    green     green          2020   0
Zone1   Mercedes    2021    amber     amber          2021   1
Zone2   BMW         2020    amber     amber          2020   1
Zone2   BMW         2021    green     green          2020   0
Zone2   Skoda       2020    amber     amber          2020   1
Zone2   Skoda       2021    green     green          2020   0
```

What I am trying to achive is to group data by Zone, Car and FiscalYear. Where we have duplicated fiscal year to be grouped I want to choose the line where Bool = 1, basically where fiscalYear equals Year, but only in the case where grouping needs to be made. This is what I'm trying to achive:

```
Zone    Car      FiscalYear Rating  FinalRating     Year   Bool
----------------------------------------------------------------
Zone1   Mercedes    2020    green     green          2020   1
Zone1   Mercedes    2021    amber     amber          2021   1
Zone2   BMW         2020    amber     amber          2020   1
Zone2   BMW         2021    green     green          2020   0
Zone2   Skoda       2020    amber     amber          2020   1
Zone2   Skoda       2021    green     green          2020   0
```

I'm using SQL Server 2014. I tried using partitions and different grouping rules but I had no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you do not need grouping. You need to select only one row for each group, so using `ROW_NUMBER()` with the appropriate `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses is a possible option:

```
SELECT Zone, Car, FiscalYear, Rating, FinalRating, Year, Bool
FROM (
   SELECT 
      *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Zone, Car, FiscalYear ORDER BY Bool DESC) AS Rn
   FROM (VALUES
      ('Zone1', 'Mercedes', '2020', 'green', 'green', 2020, 1),
      ('Zone1', 'Mercedes', '2020', 'green', 'green', 2021, 0),
      ('Zone1', 'Mercedes', '2021', 'green', 'green', 2020, 0),
      ('Zone1', 'Mercedes', '2021', 'amber', 'amber', 2021, 1),
      ('Zone2', 'BMW',      '2020', 'amber', 'amber', 2020, 1),
      ('Zone2', 'BMW',      '2021', 'green', 'green', 2020, 0),
      ('Zone2', 'Skoda',    '2020', 'amber', 'amber', 2020, 1),
      ('Zone2', 'Skoda',    '2021', 'green', 'green', 2020, 0)
   ) v (Zone, Car, FiscalYear, Rating, FinalRating, Year, Bool)   
) t
WHERE Rn = 1
```

Result:

```
Zone  Car      FiscalYear RatingFinalRating Year Bool
Zone1 Mercedes 2020       green  green      2020 1
Zone1 Mercedes 2021       amber  amber      2021 1
Zone2 BMW      2020       amber  amber      2020 1
Zone2 BMW      2021       green  green      2020 0
Zone2 Skoda    2020       amber  amber      2020 1
Zone2 Skoda    2021       green  green      2020 0
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I also tried using partition but I did not thought about using desc and where condition. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to write this is probably:

```
select top 1 with ties Zone, Car, FiscalYear, Rating, FinalRating, Year, Bool
from yourtable t
order by row_number() over (PARTITION BY Zone, Car, FiscalYear ORDER BY Bool DESC) desc
```